# This is for an assignment. I need to read in a text file and then write a text file with the original five lines written in reverse

Tags: java, file-writing

So here is the description of my assignment,

The FileCopier purpose is to read in a file, reverses the content of the file by line, and prints out a new file.

An example:

The input file contents:

This is the beginning of the file.
Second line.
This is the third line.
Fourth Line.
The end of the file.

Should be read in and the following file printed:

The end of the file.
Fourth Line.
This is the third line.
Second line.
This is the beginning of the file.

You will need to create your own input file to test with. I will use my own file to test your program.  Your program will need to make sure it satisfies the following requirements:

1. Your resources will need to be closed.
2. Exceptions will need to be appropriately handled (caught and output provided to the console or logger)
3. Your program should have the following method implemented:     public void execute(String inputFilename, String outputFilename) {    }

Submit your class file and the text file you tested with.  Feel free to zip them up.

My question is how to use the array that I have read in and print it in reverse. I have gotten pretty close I'm sure, but just can't seem to get it to properly work. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code for the assignment.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestThingsOut {

     private static String filepath = "."+File.separator+"src"+File.separator;
     private static String inputFileName = "KeyWestTemp.txt";
     private static String outputFileName = "outputTemp.txt";

    private static Scanner s1;
    private static Scanner s2;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        TestThingsOut test = new TestThingsOut();
        String inputFile = filepath.concat(inputFileName);
        String outputFile = filepath + outputFileName;

        test.execute(inputFile, outputFile);

        }

    private void execute(String inputFileName, String outputFileName) {
        String[] fileContent = readArray(inputFileName);
        writeOutFile(outputFileName, fileContent);
    }   

    public static String[] readArray(String inputFilename) {
        int ctr = 0;
        try {
            s1 = new Scanner(new File(inputFilename));
            while (s1.hasNextLine()) {
                ctr = ctr + 1;
                s1.nextLine();
            }

            String[] lines = new String[ctr];

            s2 = new Scanner(new File(inputFilename));
            for (int i = 0; i < ctr; i = i + 1) {
                lines[i] = s2.nextLine();
            }
            return lines;


    }   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
       return null;  
   }

    private void writeOutFile(String outputFileName, String[] fileContent) {
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFileName);
            String[] lines2 = readArray(inputFileName);

            for (int i = lines2.length; i >= 0; i--) {

            fileWriter.write(lines2.toString());    

        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
         }
        finally {
            if (fileWriter != null) {
                try {
                    fileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

Here is the file that I am trying to read in,

1. Hey Guys
   2  How are you 
   3  I am very good
   4  Thanks
   5  This is line 5

which originally worked and I could print it out using Systemoutprint, but I have to follow the instructions of the assignment and write it out to another file, which I can't quite figure out.

Comment: "Can't quite figure it out" - that's why it's YOUR assignment, not ours.

Comment: What portion of the code do you attempt to reverse the array?

Comment: @MackProgramsAlot I try to reverse the array in the writeOutFile method. In the Array String[] lines2.

Comment: @duffymo which is why I said any help or guidance would be appreciated. New to programming and was hoping the community would be a little more understanding of early issues. Not looking for the direct solution, just more understanding. Don't think your response was necessary.

Comment: @SteveSmith that is the guidance.  Don't think your question is necessary.

Comment: Inside the loop that starts with `for (int i = lines2.length; i >= 0; i--) {`, you don't seem to have used `i` at all - and I think you probably need to use it somehow - probably as an index to that array `lines2`.  Also, it should start with `int i = lines2.length - 1`, because that's the largest index in the array.  So think about what you might have to change the line inside the loop to.

Comment: @duffymo from looking over this website for quite some time before posting, I figured asking what I asked was acceptable to this website's standards. I saw very similar posts that were asked in the same manner that I did so I am just confused why mine isn't fine? Any pointers on that side of stuff would be appreciated because I see you are a very respected member in this community.

Comment: @SteveSmith what you'll realize soon enough, this site is filled with police who think they'll be remembered for their stack overflow policing when they die.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a `String` array you could use a `ArrayList` or `Vector` to store the lines of file.

```
ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
```

This `ArrayList` will hold the lines of the file and then you can write the same to a different file by iterating over the ArrayList.

```
//Reading the file
while (s1.hasNextLine()) {
           String s= s1.nextLine();
           arr.add(s);
        }

//Writing the file
for (int i = arr.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {

        fileWriter.write(arr.get(i).toString());
```